# Does SSTab1.TabPages.Item(?) start from 0 or 1?

Tags: c#

Hallo all,

short question:

Does the index x in SSTab1.TabPages.Item(x) start from 0 or from 1? How could I find out which tab corresponds to which item(x)?

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 0):

In general, all collections in C# are 0-indexed. However, it's difficult to be 100% sure unless we know the exact type of SSTab1.